# Redux Toolkit: TypeError: Cannot read property 'isLoggedIn' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I'm trying to use useSelector hook from react-redux with a selector from redux-toolkit slice in my custom hook and i'm getting the following error.

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'isLoggedIn' of undefined

store.ts:

```
import { configureStore, ThunkAction, Action } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import authReducer from './authSlice';

export const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    auth: authReducer,
  },
});

export type RootState = ReturnType<typeof store.getState>;
export type AppThunk<ReturnType = void> = ThunkAction<
  ReturnType,
  RootState,
  unknown,
  Action<string>
>;
```

authSlice.ts:

```
import { createSlice, PayloadAction } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import authService from '../services/authService';
import { UserWithDetails } from '../types/User';
import { AppThunk, RootState } from './store';
import toast from 'react-hot-toast';

interface AuthState {
  isLoggedIn: boolean;
  user: UserWithDetails | null;
}

const initialState: AuthState = {
  isLoggedIn: localStorage.getItem('accessToken') ? true : false,
  user: localStorage.getItem('authenticatedUser')
    ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('authenticatedUser') as string)
    : null,
};

export const authSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'auth',
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    login: (state, action: PayloadAction<UserWithDetails>) => {
      state.user = action.payload;
      state.isLoggedIn = true;
    },
    logout: (state) => {
      state.user = null;
      state.isLoggedIn = false;
    },
  },
});

const { login, logout } = authSlice.actions;

export const loginUser = (accessToken: string): AppThunk => async (
  dispatch
) => {
  localStorage.setItem('accessToken', accessToken);

  const user = await authService.me();
  localStorage.setItem('authenticatedUser', JSON.stringify(user));

  dispatch(login(user));

  toast.success('You have been logged in.');
};

export const logoutUser = (): AppThunk => (dispatch) => {
  localStorage.removeItem('accessToken');
  localStorage.removeItem('authenticatedUser');

  dispatch(logout());

  toast.success('You have been logged out.');
};

export const selectIsLoggedIn = (state: RootState) => state.auth.isLoggedIn;
export const selectUser = (state: RootState) => state.auth.user;

export default authSlice.reducer;
```

useAuth.ts

```
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { selectIsLoggedIn, selectUser } from '../store/authSlice';

const useAuth = () => {
  const isLoggedIn = useSelector(selectIsLoggedIn);
  const user = useSelector(selectUser);

  return {
    isLoggedIn,
    user,
  };
};

export default useAuth;
```

When i'm using inline selector it works fine:

```
const isLoggedIn = useSelector((state: RootState) => state.auth.isLoggedIn);
```

I don't understand why a selector from a slice doesn't work. Please help. Thank you.

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MEj55.png)

Comment: Check out the two errors above that one -- something is wrong with the reducer.    First things first, make sure that `import authReducer from './authSlice';` is the correct path.  Your code is correct and you are exporting the reducer as the default so it has to be a wrong path or something like that.

Comment: It works now. The problem was that I tried to use the store instance in a util module independent of react. I moved this util module (axios interceptor) to index.tsx where i initialize the store.

Comment: @MaksymilianStępak could you please share your faulty code sample? I guess we're facing similar issue